# Calculate area between two curves in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart, integral

I want to calculate and draw a chart indicating the difference between this two curves

```
 XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Series 1");
    series1.add(1, 1);
    series1.add(2, 2);
    series1.add(3, 3);

    XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("Series 2");
    series2.add(1, 3);
    series2.add(2, 4);
    series2.add(3, 5);
```

In mathematics I have to calculate a finite integral to solve this problem, but with JFreeChart, how can I do it?
Can you explain and maybe code it? I am new on JFreeChart.
Thank you.

Comment: A finite integral is used to calculate the are under a continuous curve, where that curve is defined by a formula, for some range on some axis. The difference between two curves is simply gotten by subtracting one curve (usually the one with the higher values) from the other curve.

Comment: No built-in support, AFAIK. Maybe look at `org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.integration`, mentioned [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html). See also `org.jfree.data.function`.